# pagination data with laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, pagination

I´m traying to paginate my results of query, but i have a problem with this. I have this code in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = (object) array(
            'title' => trans('web.blog_title'),
            'description' => trans('web.blog_header_info'),
        );

        $posts = \DB::table('blogs')->paginate(5);
    

        return view('web.blog')->with('data', $data)->with('posts', [ 'data' => $posts[0] ]);
    }
```

and in my view:

```
<div class="pagination">
   <span>{{$posts->links()}}</span>
</div>
```

but i have one error when render blade:

```
Call to a member function links() on array (View: C:\wamp64\www\guiaPaladar\resources\views\web\blog.blade.php)
```

i did a print_r and this it´s result:

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator Object ( [total:protected] => 1 [lastPage:protected] => 1 [items:protected] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 [name] => prueba [description] => Es una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba [content] =>
Es una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin fotoEs una prueba de post sin foto

[restaurant_id] => [created_at] => 2021-02-10 07:49:36 [updated_at] => 2021-02-10 08:07:28 [url] => prueba [dynamiclink] => ) ) ) [perPage:protected] => 5 [currentPage:protected] => 1 [path:protected] => http://guiapaladar.local/blog [query:protected] => Array ( ) [fragment:protected] => [pageName:protected] => page [onEachSide] => 3 [options:protected] => Array ( [path] => http://guiapaladar.local/blog [pageName] => page ) )
```

so that, i can show my post in my blog page, but when render blade i can´t show it...

What are i doing wrong?

thanks for help me

**update**

```
<div class="pagination">                           
   {{ $posts->links() }}
</div>
```

result:

```
<div class="pagination">
                                
                                
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
return view('web.blog')->with('data', $data)->with('posts', [ 'data' => $posts[0] ]);
```

to:

```
return view('web.blog')->with('data', $data)->with('posts', $posts);
```

Comment: I've tested exactly this code here and it worked... Are you on your correct blade template?? "/web/blog.blade.php" ???

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it